# How do I implement a get-method for an enum that returns the right type?

Tags: generics, rust, enums

I have an enum that holds variants which contain certain types. I want to write a `get` method that automatically returns the right type if the enum variant contains this type.

```
pub enum Var {
    Switch(bool),
    PositiveInteger(u32),
    Integer(i32),
    PositiveFloat(f64),
    Float(f64),
    Phase(f64), // a float x, where 0.0 <= x < 2Pi
    Turn(f64), // the same, but with 0.0 <= x < 1.0
}
```

Somewhere else in the code I want to get the `value` inside the variant e.g. `PositiveFloat( value )`. But it doesn't seem possible (to me) to write a generic function, like this:

```
impl Var {
    pub fn get<T>(&self) -> T 
where
    T: Default,
{
        match self {
            Var::Switch(value) => value,
            Var::PositiveInteger(value) => value,
            // etc
}
```

I instead seem to have to implement a different get-method for each variant of the enum: `get_positive_integer()`, `get_integer()`, etc.
Maybe I am looking about the problem the wrong way. What I want to achieve something like this:

```
let positive_integer = Var::PositiveInteger(1);
let x: u32 = positive_integer.get();

let float = Var::Float(0.1);
let y: f64 = float.get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a trait for that:

```rust
pub trait VarTypes: Sized {
    fn get(var: &Var) -> Option<Self>;
}

impl VarTypes for bool {
    fn get(var: &Var) -> Option<Self> {
        match *var {
            Var::Switch(v) => Some(v),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}

impl VarTypes for u32 {
    fn get(var: &Var) -> Option<Self> {
        match *var {
            Var::PositiveInteger(v) => Some(v),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}

impl VarTypes for i32 {
    fn get(var: &Var) -> Option<Self> {
        match *var {
            Var::Integer(v) => Some(v),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}

impl VarTypes for f64 {
    fn get(var: &Var) -> Option<Self> {
        match *var {
            Var::PositiveFloat(v) | Var::Float(v) | Var::Phase(v) | Var::Turn(v) => Some(v),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can implement `get()` with it:

```rust
impl Var {
    pub fn get<T>(&self) -> T
    where
        T: VarTypes + Default,
    {
        T::get(self).unwrap_or_default()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
That helps tremendously. I didn't think of Traits here.

Answer (score 3):

You can't define the method in an `impl Var` directly because you'd need a different implementation for every type. What you can do instead is define a generic trait and implement that for every type you want:

```rust
trait Get<T> {
    fn get(&self) -> Option<T>;
}

impl Get<bool> for Var {
    fn get(&self) -> Option<bool> {
        match self {
            Var::Switch(value) => Some(*value),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}

impl Get<u32> for Var {
    fn get(&self) -> Option<u32> {
        match self {
            Var::PositiveInteger(v) => Some(*v),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}

impl Get<f64> for Var {
    fn get(&self) -> Option<f64> {
        match self {
            Var::PositiveFloat(v) | Var::Float(v) | Var::Phase(v) | Var::Turn(v) => Some(*v),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
// …
```

I changed the return type to `Option<T>` because that relaxes the requirement on `T` and is more in line like other similar methods (`slice::get`, ...) and you can regain your semantics with a simple `unwrap_or_default()`:

```rust
let positive_integer = Var::PositiveInteger(1);
let x: u32 = positive_integer.get().unwrap_or_default();
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I used it exactly like you here and it works really well. Also the error-handling. Fantastic!